# How to use another function in onPress passed as prop in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a reusable component `AppFormButtonGroup`

It accepts props `buttons` `name` `value` `onPress` `selectedIndex` `...props`

It also uses `const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();`

It is configured like this:

```
<ButtonGroup
   buttons={buttons}
   selectedIndex={selectedIndex}
   onPress={onPress}
   {...props}
/>
```

For its application, say, on another file, I use it like this:

```
<AppFormButtonGroup
   name="country"
   buttons={countries}
   selectedIndex={selectedCountryIndex}
   onPress={(value) => {
      setCountry(countries[value])
      setSelectedCountryIndex(value)
      setIsCountrySheetVisible(false)
   }}
   value={country}
/>
```

The onPress prop's content is transferred to the `AppFormButtonGroup` and is then applied. It is working as of this moment.

My problem is how can I use the `setFieldValue` inside the `AppFormButtonGroup`'s onPress prop if I have already set the content on the onPress prop on the other file?

Here is one of my aim:

`AppFormButtonGroup.js`

```
onPress={() => {
   setFieldValue(name, value);
}}
```

This is working as intended, but it gets overwritten by the onPress prop with [code below] in it

`AnotherFile.js`

```
onPress={(value) => {
      setCountry(countries[value])
      setSelectedCountryIndex(value)
      setIsCountrySheetVisible(false)
   }}
```

How can I use both together?

I am not sure if this is a syntax error on my part or the very approach I am making is something very inefficient and if you would provide a better approach I'd very much appreciate it!

Thank you!

I have tried the following but to no avail:

`onPress={[onPress,setFieldValue(name, value)]}`

I have also tried declaring and using `const { setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();` on the other file but it seems it's not working.

My question's point is how can I use the following in one onPress?

```
setCountry(countries[value])
setSelectedCountryIndex(value)
setIsCountrySheetVisible(false)
setFieldValue(name, value)
```

When `setFieldValue(name, value)` can only be used inside `AppFormButtonGroup.js`

Answer (score 0):

In the child first update the local state and then call the parent handler. Something like this:

```
const Child = ({onPress}) => { 
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return <Button
    title={`${count}`}
    onPress={() => {
      setCount(count + 1)
      onPress(count + 1)
    }}
  />
}

const Parent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  return <>
      <Child
        onPress={(c) => setCount(c)}
      />
      <Text>{`Child count ${count}`}</Text>
  </>
};
```